# Same Jquery validation applied for register and update but getting the issue on a remote method for email

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter and jQuery validation. I have a registration form in that fields are `Firstname, Lastname, email, mobile`. Jquery validation is working perfectly. I am using the remote method to check the email id is existed or not in the database which also works. There is no issue in the form while registration.

Come to the update records

I am using the same jquery validation for both the form "Registration" and "Update". Even validation is also working but there is some issue in the remote method.

I haven't updated my email and then click on submit button it's showing "Email id already exist". AS per the process, this is the right but is there any other way, without update the email remote method should not call? or if the user updates the email field then remote method call for an update? or else should I check email before updating the record? 
or should I use separate validation for an update?

What is the best way to use? Any other idea?

**Jquery Validation**

```
$("#emp_register").validate({
        // Specify the validation rules
        rules: {
           firstname:{
                 required: true,
                 minlength:3,
                maxlength:50
           },
          lastname:{
                 required: true,
                 minlength:3,
                maxlength:50
           },
            email: {
                required: true,
                 email:true,
                 remote: {
                    url: baseUrl + "/Employee_control/checkemail_exist",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                          email: function () {
                               return $("#email").val();
                        }}
                 }
            },
          mobileno: {
                required: true,
                number:true,
                minlength:10,
                maxlength: 10

            }
   },
      messages: {
        email: {remote: "This email is already registered!"
      }
    },
         submitHandler: function(form) {
         form.submit();
         }
    });
```

**Registration**

```
public function employee_register(){
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Firstname', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Lastname', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobileno', 'Mobile no', 'trim|required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                      $this->index();
                 }
                 else
                {
        $data = array(
                'firstname'=>$this->input->post('firstname');,
                'lastname'=>$this->input->post('lastname'),
                'email_id'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'mobileno'=>$this->input->post('mobileno'),
                 );
              $secure_data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
               $this->db->insert('tbl_employee',$secure_data);  
               redirect("Employee_control/index");   
          }

    }
```

**Update**

```
public function update_employee_info(){
    $update_key_id=$this->encryption->decrypt(base64_decode($this->input->get('key')));

    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="error">', '</div>');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Firstname', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Lastname', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|max_length[25]');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobileno', 'Mobile no', 'trim|required|regex_match[/^[0-9]{10}$/]');
           if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                     $this->load->view('employee/employee_edit');
                 }
                 else
                {

    $updateData = array(
                'firstname'=>$this->input->post('firstname'),
                'lastname'=>$this->input->post('lastname'),
                'email_id'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'mobileno'=>$this->input->post('mobileno')
              );
           $secure_updateData = $this->security->xss_clean($updateData);
            $this->db->where('id', $update_key_id);
            $this->db->update('tbl_employee', $secure_updateData);   
            redirect("Employee_control/employee_list"); 
                }
}
```

Comment: you should use separate validation for an update with only required field for email and on change use validation for email exits,  better set email column of table `unique`

Comment: @pradeep, separate validation for all the fields for only email field?

Comment: obviously you are using id for the form you have to do it separately

Comment: @pradeep, Yes, I know that I forgot to change it. Instated of Id I will use the class.

Comment: @pradeep, can you help me out in this issue?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166869/how-to-display-the-secondary-records-in-the-data-table-child-row-with-respective

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is an `<input>` (perhaps hidden) on the registration form named "key" like there is on the update form. On the registration form the value is probably blank or an empty string.

If that's true one solution might be to pass the `email` and `key` values in the JQuery validation of email.

For example this might work:

```
data:{
    key: function () {
    return $("#key").val();
    },
    email: function () {
    return $("#email").val();
    }
},
```

The `checkemail_exist()` method can use the `key` to determine if this is an update or insert situation. I have made up a model and some modle->methods since you don't share those. Hopefully the intention for these is clear.

```
public function checkemail_exist()
{
    $key = $this->input->get('key');  
    $email = $this->input->get('email');

    if(!empty($key)) //then this is an update
    {
        // This would be the place to decrypt $key if needed

        // get the email associated with the user
        $existing_email = $this->db->user_model->get_email($key);

        if($email == $existing_email)
        {
            //the email input is unchanged from a previously validated value
            return true;
        }
    }

    //With either a new user or exiting user who has changed their email
    //the new input must be unique
    //For example, this made up model->method returns true if the email isn't on file
    return $this->user_model->check_unique_email($email);
}
```

If you are using the jQuery validation plugin I think you are I understand the return needs to be more than a simple boolean like is done above. I'll leave that implementation detail to you.

Comment: So I have to check the previous email id and compare the new email id. if both same then no remote method if both are not same then remote method should apply. right?

Comment: `checkemail_exist()` is the remote method. If this is an update and old and new are the same then email is valid. If old and new are different or if this is an insert then the email is valid if it is unique.